# How to save the image in binary format?

Tags: c#

I have appended the selected file in formData and send to server side using XML request. In server-side, I need to save the received file in binary format.

My existing code is

```
var httpPostedFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["MyFiles"];

var fileSave = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("SavedFiles");

Directory.CreateDirectory(fileSave);

var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(fileSave, httpPostedFile.FileName);
```

Up to this, a folder has been created.  I don't know how to save the file as a binary format in the created location.

**Blindly** I have tried below

```
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileSavePath);
byte[] b;
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
   b = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);                         
}
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
{
bw.Write(b);
}
```

but it throws the exception. can you please suggest how to achieve my need here?

Comment: It almost looks like you're reading the bytes from an empty/new files using `fs`, which is throwing an error since it's null. Is there anything at the end of `fileSavePath` at runtime? If so, what are the contents?

Comment: Hi James,

target folder will be empty. We need to save the file yet. We can get the file details in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["MyFiles"]

My question is.

Can we save the new file in binary format?

Comment: I dont know about the behavior of binary reader and writter.

Comment: "but it throws the exception" - What exception does it throw? Please include the _full_ exception.

Comment: threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147467261
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    Source: null
    StackTrace: null
    TargetSite: null

Comment: "I dont know about the behavior of binary reader and writter." - Have your tried looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) or searching for examples showing how to use them?

Answer (score 1):

To save a posted file, assuming httpPostedFile is not null, you could simply use `SaveAs(...)`

```
HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile = ...

// I've changed your method to use Path.GetFileName(...) to ensure that there are no path elements in the input filename.
var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(fileSave, Path.GetFileName(httpPostedFile.FileName));
httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your suggestion. How to save it in a binary format?

Comment: @Joy What do you mean "in a binary format"? It will save the bytes the same as it receives them.

Comment: Can i convert the received file to binary format before save the file and pass the converted data to save in local machine

Comment: @Joy There seems to be a misunderstanding on your part or a lack of information in your question. If you receive a text file, you can't "convert it to a binary format", for example. By definition of it being a text file, it isn't a binary format.

Comment: I need to this only for image files

Comment: Is there something special that you're doing to send these files to the server, which you need to undo to convert them back into a binary format? I don't really understand the problem you're facing. Perhaps you could include any special logic you're using to send the images in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171206/discussion-between-joy-and-john).